# Mac book pro manufacturing year

Tags: serial-number, system-information, hardware

How to identify mac book pro product manufacturing year? And not the product release date.
example is mac book pro series launched in 2012 but what is its product manufactured date?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Yosemite or later, click Apple symbol (top left) -> About This Mac & it's there.

Comment: That only gives the model year, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

There's a freeware app from Micromat, the makers of TechTool Pro, called [MachineProfile](https://www.micromat.com/products/machineprofile) which will give detailed information…

[image]

It can even give away anomalies - for instance, my machine shows as a 2010 (which should make it a 4,1) & yet it registers as a 5,1. That's because it's had a hardware upgrade to 2012 spec.